# Why are my params in data-params ignored by Rails UJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have form that I change `data-params="save=autosave" with a click handler.
I can verify the DOM changes are made in Chrome's dev tools. When I click submit, the form submits fine, but the params are not appended to the request.

Before the click:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/practice_scores/17" 
class="assessment__answer-form" data-params="save=normal" data-remote="true" 
id="edit_practice_score_17" method="post">
</form>
```

After the click:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/practice_scores/17" 
class="assessment__answer-form" data-params="save=autosave" data-remote="true"   
id="edit_practice_score_17" method="post">
</form>
```

Log:

```
Started PATCH "/practice_scores/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-16 14:37:06 -0800
Processing by PracticeScoresController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "practice_score"=>
  {"assessment_id"=>"1", "practice_id"=>"7", "context"=>"respondent", 
  "score_id"=>"33", "justification"=>"", "future_plan"=>""}, "id"=>"17"}
```

I'm confused as to why the params are not sent. In another place in my app, I change `data-params` on a remote link with a JS response and it submits correctly.

Why is `data-params` ignored on this form?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code for the driver, data-params are not supported. So this won't work.

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/pull/405) to fix the issue.